# Nested List Weight Sum algorithm issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to solve this problem "Nested List Weight Sum": https://leetcode.com/problems/nested-list-weight-sum/description/

**Problem:**

> Given the list [[1,1],2,[1,1]], return 10. (four 1's at depth 2, one 2
>   at depth 1)

This is my solution.

```
var depthSum = function (nestedList, sum=0, depth=1) {
    nestedList.forEach((val) => {
        if (Array.isArray(val)) {
            depth = depth+1;
            return depthSum(val, sum, depth);
        } else {
            sum += val * depth;
        }
    });
    return sum;
};
```

Not sure what I'm missing. When I debug it, at some point I get the answer but `return sum` does not kick in and i get a different answer.

Can someone point me the bug?

Comment: It doesn't do any good to `return` something from a `.forEach()` iteration.

Comment: Also don't increment `depth` like that; just pass `depth + 1` in the recursive call.

Comment: Got it. Thanks! but when I submit it on leetcode, i still get expected solution as `NaN`

Comment: This is my code:

```
var depthSum = function (nestedList, sum=0, depth=1) {
    for(let i=0; i<nestedList.length; i++){
        let val = nestedList[i];
        if (Array.isArray(val)) {
            return depthSum(val, sum, depth+1);
        } else {
            sum += val * depth;
        }
    };
    return sum;
};
```

Comment: You've still got that pointless `return` in the `.forEach()` callback. Adding code in comments does not work very well; update the question if you want to add more context.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and omit the `sum` for every level by returning a sum for each level.

```js
function depthSum(nestedList, level = 1) {
    return nestedList.reduce((sum, val) =>
        sum + (Array.isArray(val)
            ? depthSum(val, level + 1)
            : level * val),
        0);
};

console.log(depthSum([[1, 1], 2, [1, 1]]));
```

Answer (score 2):

So one way to tackle it.

There's no sense in returning from inside your `forEach`, what you should instead do is add the total from the recursive call to your current total. And since you are doing that, you don't need to have the `sum` be a parameter to your `depthSum` function

```js
var nestedList = [[1,1],2,[1,1]];

var depthSum = function(nestedList, depth = 1) {
  var sum = 0;
  nestedList.forEach((val) => {
    if (Array.isArray(val)) {
      sum += depthSum(val, depth + 1);
    } else {
      sum += val * depth;
    }
  });
  return sum;
};

console.log(depthSum(nestedList))
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the requirement of the code in Leetcode the following is the Working code.

```
    var depthSum = function (nestedList,  depth=1) {
    var res = 0;
    nestedList.forEach((val) => {
        if (val.isInteger() === false) {
            res += depthSum(val.getList(),  depth + 1);
        } else {
            res += val.getInteger() * depth;
        }
    });
    return res;
};
```

You can't use `Array.isArray()` because all the members will return false. and also you can't access the values or list directly. You need to access through their API. The input to the function is not simply an array. See the input type and the APIs present from the specification as follow:

```
     * function NestedInteger() {
 *
 *     Return true if this NestedInteger holds a single integer, rather than a nested list.
 *     @return {boolean}
 *     this.isInteger = function() {
 *         ...
 *     };
 *
 *     Return the single integer that this NestedInteger holds, if it holds a single integer
 *     Return null if this NestedInteger holds a nested list
 *     @return {integer}
 *     this.getInteger = function() {
 *         ...
 *     };
 *
 *     Set this NestedInteger to hold a single integer equal to value.
 *     @return {void}
 *     this.setInteger = function(value) {
 *         ...
 *     };
 *
 *     Set this NestedInteger to hold a nested list and adds a nested integer elem to it.
 *     @return {void}
 *     this.add = function(elem) {
 *         ...
 *     };
 *
 *     Return the nested list that this NestedInteger holds, if it holds a nested list
 *     Return null if this NestedInteger holds a single integer
 *     @return {NestedInteger[]}
 *     this.getList = function() {
 *         ...
 *     };
 * };
 */
/**
 * @param {NestedInteger[]} nestedList
 * @return {number}
 */
```